# Why isn't `curve_fit` able to estimate the covariance of the parameter if the parameter fits exactly?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, covariance

I don't understand `curve_fit` isn't able to estimate the covariance of the parameter, thus raising the `OptimizeWarning` below. The following MCVE explains my problem:

**MCVE python snippet**

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
func = lambda x, a: a * x
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f = func, xdata = [1], ydata = [1])
print(popt, pcov)
```

**Output**

```
\python-3.4.4\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py:715:
OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
category=OptimizeWarning)

[ 1.] [[ inf]]
```

For `a = 1` the function fits `xdata` and `ydata` exactly. Why isn't the error/variance `0`, or something close to `0`, but `inf` instead?

There is this quote from the [`curve_fit` SciPy Reference Guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

> If the Jacobian matrix at the solution doesn’t have a full rank, then ‘lm’ method returns a matrix filled with np.inf, on the other hand ‘trf’ and ‘dogbox’ methods use Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse to compute the covariance matrix.

So, what's the underlying problem? Why doesn't the Jacobian matrix at the solution have a full rank?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The formula for the covariance of the parameters ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Parameter_errors_and_correlation)) has the number of degrees of freedom in the denominator. The degrees of freedoms are computed as (number of data points) - (number of parameters), which is 1 - 1 = 0 in your example. And [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.1/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L706) is where SciPy checks the number of degrees of freedom before dividing by it.

With `xdata = [1, 2], ydata = [1, 2]` you would get zero covariance (note that the model still fits exactly: exact fit is not the problem).

This is the same sort of issue as sample variance being undefined if the sample size N is 1 (the formula for sample variance has (N-1) in the denominator). If we only took size=1 sample out of the population, we don't estimate the  variance by zero, we know nothing about the variance.

Comment: Your answer helped me figure out that the dimensions of my arrays were wrong, perhaps other people can have that same problem to check.