# scipy.optimize.curve_fit return inf pcov

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I use curve_fit to fit a very simple line  as below code:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

x = [6.6000000000000005, 7.599]
y = [123.9835274456227, 144.9319749893788]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y,method='dogbox',p0=[20,-15])
print(popt) # get [ 20.96941696 -14.4146245 ]
print(pcov) # get [[inf inf], [inf inf]]
```

But the pcov result is inf. How can I get correct pcov values ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't \`curve\_fit\` able to estimate the covariance of the parameter if the parameter fits exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725377/why-isnt-curve-fit-able-to-estimate-the-covariance-of-the-parameter-if-the-pa)

Comment: @joni, thanks for the comment. I do not think this is my case. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The result should be no value, since two points fit curve should no parameter error. So the covariance of parameters is zero.